# how to display default text value on span after erasing the value typed on input

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've an `input` and its default text and if i type inside the `input` i get that in another `span` but if I erase and type a new `input value` and finally if i erase that `input value` and now the `input value` is empty and the `span text` is also empty so how do I set the `default span` value to something similar to `input default value`.

### HTML

```
<input type="text" value="Sample"/>
<span>Sample Text</span>
```

### jQuery

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
var value = $("input").val();
$( "span" ).text(value);
});
```

Comment: You can put `var value = $("input").val();$( "span" ).text(value);` in `$(document).ready()` function as well.

Comment: **1.** Use `$(this)` inside event handler to get the value of current input. **2.** `$('span')` will select all the `<span>` elements on the page, use some specific selector. **Code:** `$("input").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  value = value.length ? value : 'Default Value';
  $('span').text(value);
});` [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xgte2bvt/)

Comment: What does ? mark resemble?

Comment: why don't you use placeholder?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers Yah even thats fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an if/else.

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value.length > 0){
    $( "span" ).text(value);
  } else {
    $( "span").text('Some default value');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, all you need is a condition inside your keyup to check if your input field has any value or not and set span text accordingly.

```js
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = val.length ? val : 'Sample Text';
  $("span").text(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Sample"/>
<span>Sample Text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you get default text in both `input` field and in `span`

Below is the solution:

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n8nsb7uy/)**

```js
$("input").keyup(function() {
var value = $("input").val();
if(value == "") {
$('input').val($('input').val() + 'default text');
 value = "default text";
}
$( "span" ).text(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Sample"/>
<span>Sample Text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("span").text(val.length != 0 ? val : ($("span").attr('data-default')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type Your Text : <input type="text" value="Default Span Text"/>
<span data-default="Default Span Text">Default Span Text</span>
```